# react-hook-form material-ui Form submit works only once

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form with material-ui. I am wrapping a form and input component with my custom component. Validation on this form works only once. For next time onwards, this form does not respond, neither get submitted not validated. Can someone please help me understand what's going wrong here ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-material-ui-ugiz4

Comment: your example is quite confusing... maybe clean it up and keep it small. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-material-ui-euo6g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think react hook form input which you are using is changed to controller now. You could check in the update section of this [link](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form-input) . Here is [react hook controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#Controller) link.

I changed the react hook input form to controller and observed that submit is trigger every time
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-material-ui-eereh